# Toggle shinydashboard menuItems based on input parameters

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am building a large shinydashboard app that can take two kinds of data, *monthly* or *interval*. Some tabs should be shown when "Monthly" is selected from a dropdown and hidden when "Interval" is selected (and vice versa).

I tried assigning two classes, "OnlyMonthly" and "OnlyInterval," to the relevant `menuItem()`s by wrapping them in `div()` tags, and then using `shinyJS`'s `toggle()` command to show ".OnlyMonthly" when "Monthly" is selected and to hide ".OnlyInterval," but the formatting of the menu is affected and it doesn't work.

Here's the code for a basic app:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Toggle Menu'),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Item 1', tabName = 'item1',
        menuSubItem('Item A', tabName = 'item1A'),
        # just hide Item B
        div(menuSubItem('Item B', tabName = 'item1B'), class = 'OnlyMonthly')
      ),

      # hide all of Item 2, including C and D
      div(class = 'OnlyInterval',
        menuItem('Item 2', tabName = 'item2',
          menuSubItem('Item C', tabName = 'item2C'),
          menuSubItem('Item D', tabName = 'item2D')
        )
      )

    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput(inputId = 'monthly_vs_interval', label = 'Data type',choices = c('Monthly','Interval'))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    toggle(selector = ".OnlyMonthly", input$monthly_vs_interval == 'Monthly')
    toggle(selector = ".OnlyInterval", input$monthly_vs_interval == 'Interval')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing, I found that `conditionalPanel` properly shows/hides the tabs but  the formatting is still affected. It seems `sidebarMenu` only allows `menuItem`s as childs and the same is true for `menuItem` and `menuSubItem`. You can probably hide the `menuItem` via it's `id` (see `?menuItem`) but there might be no way to show/hide `menuSubItem`s without affecting the formatting.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Toggle Menu'),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Item 1', tabName = 'item1',
               menuSubItem('Item A', tabName = 'item1A'),
               # just hide Item B
               conditionalPanel(menuSubItem('Item B', tabName = 'item1B'), 
                                condition = "input.monthly_vs_interval == 'Monthly'")
      ),

      # hide all of Item 2, including C and D
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.monthly_vs_interval == 'Interval'",
          menuItem('Item 2', tabName = 'item2',
                   menuSubItem('Item C', tabName = 'item2C'),
                   menuSubItem('Item D', tabName = 'item2D')
          )
      )

    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    selectInput(inputId = 'monthly_vs_interval', label = 'Data type',
                choices = c('Monthly', 'Interval'))
  )
)

server <- function(...){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**: Actually, only `sidebarMenu` has an `id` argument. Using an argument named `id` in `menuSubItem` leads to a syntax error and using show/hide via `id` for `menuItem`s leads to unexpected results. I guess you can always code it the "dirty" way by using `conditionalPanel` outside of the `sidebarMenu`. Note however, that this approach is kind of [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Toggle Menu'),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.monthly_vs_interval == 'Monthly'",
      sidebarMenu(menuItem(
        'Item 1', tabName = 'item1',
        menuSubItem('Item A', tabName = 'item1A'),
        menuSubItem('Item B', tabName = 'item1B')
      ))
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.monthly_vs_interval == 'Interval'",
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem('Item 1', tabName = 'item1',
                 menuSubItem('Item A', tabName = 'item1A')
        ),
        menuItem('Item 2', tabName = 'item2',
                 menuSubItem('Item C', tabName = 'item2C'),
                 menuSubItem('Item D', tabName = 'item2D')
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    selectInput(inputId = 'monthly_vs_interval', label = 'Data type',
                choices = c('Monthly', 'Interval'))
  )
)

server <- function(...){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```